# Recursing through related data from database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-lists

Here is the thing, am trying to generate html unordered list using the data from database in order by which they are related. lets say **A** is the parent of **B** and **C** and **B** is the parent of **D** i want **B** and **C** to be two list items inside unordered list inside **A** and **D** as a list item inside unodered list within B and so on...

**the structure of my table looks like:**

```
+-----+------+--------+
| uid | name | parent |
+-----+------+--------+
|   1 | A    |      0 |
|   2 | B    |      1 |
|   3 | C    |      1 |
|   4 | D    |      2 |
|   5 | E    |      3 |
|   7 | G    |      3 |
|   9 | H    |      4 |
|  10 | I    |      4 |
|  11 | J    |      7 |
+-----+------+--------+
```

**PHP code**

```php
function recurse($id){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM binary_tbl WHERE `uid`='{$id}' ";
    // echo $sql;
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
    // var_dump($conn);
    $output = '';
    while($r = $res->fetch_assoc()){

        $output .= "<li> <a href=\"#\">".$r['name']."</a>";
        $query_member = "SELECT * FROM binary_tbl WHERE parent= $id";
        $res_member = $conn->query($query_member);
        while($rm = $res_member->fetch_assoc())
        {
                    $output .=  recurse($rm['uid']).'</li>';
        }       
        return '<ul>'.$output.'</ul>';
    }
}
```

**Expected result**

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">A</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">D</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">I</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">C</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">G</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">J</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Output:**
the output has too many unordered list tags and does not follow the order i want it to be

```html
<ul>
                <li> <a href="#">A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">B</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">D</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li> <a href="#">H</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <ul>
                                    <li> <a href="#">I</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#">C</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a href="#">E</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">G</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">J</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </ul>
```

Comment: I recommend you don't start writing HTML immediately, put them in nested arrays first and generate the HTML afterwards.

Comment: i have thought about it but have difficulties getting them into a multi-dimensional array